# How to convert month of year to first month

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get a date range from current date to previous 3 years
And previous 3 yr data should start with Jan 01.
Below is the code snippet that I have tried.

```
dateDF = spark.sql("select current_date() as current_date, add_months(current_date(),-36) as end_date")
dateDF =  dateDF.withColumn("end_date_first_date", F.trunc("end_date", "month")).withColumn("end_date_first_date_first_month",lit(''))
dateDF.show()

+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|current_date|  end_date|end_date_first_date|end_date_first_date_first_month|
+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|  2021-04-09|2018-04-09|         2018-04-01|                               |
+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Here I was able to get first date, but how can I get first month. Is there any pre defined functions?

Expected output

```
+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|current_date|  end_date|end_date_first_date|end_date_first_date_first_month|
+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|  2021-04-09|2018-04-09|         2018-04-01|   2018-01-01                  |
+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `year` instead of `month` in `F.trunc`:

```
dateDF = dateDF.withColumn(
    "end_date_first_date", 
    F.trunc("end_date", "month")
).withColumn(
    "end_date_first_date_first_month",
    F.trunc("end_date", "year")
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell to pick a particular month from end_date. eg:here end_date is 2018-01-01,lets say I need the month as "October" ie 2018-10-01, whether that too can be achieved using F.trunc?

Comment: You can use `add_months`, e.g. `F.add_months(F.trunc("end_date", "year"), 9)`

Comment: Oh ok cool. That can be achieved calling an add_months. Got it